# SyntaxError with async

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to get into the new `async` property, but I have an error that I can not understand:

[image]

Here is my code :

```
module.exports.action = async (message, command, args) => {

    // Show response
    await message.reply('test');

};
```

----- OR -----

[image]

Here is my code :

```
module.exports.action = async function (message, command, args) {

    // Show response
    await message.reply('test');

};
```

You have an idea?

**SOLUTION**

> Just update my node JS version >= 7.x

Comment: what's your node version?

Comment: My node version is v6.11.3

Comment: that's too early for async, isn't it? you need node 8.7 or greater

Comment: You need babel.

Comment: It's work. @JaromandaX show your answer that I can validate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

change `test().then((a) => document.write(a))` to `test().then((a) => console.log(a))` and in nodejs
[image]

```js
const test = async (message, command, args) => {

    // Show response
    return await Promise.resolve('result!!');

};


test().then((a) => console.log(a))
```

---old answer---

It's working, use latest nodejs and it will work, or you can use babel, or use Promise only

```js
const test = async(message, command, args) => {

  // Show response
  return await Promise.resolve('result!!');

};


test().then((a) => document.write(a))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what does this browser code have to do with nodejs?

Comment: @JaromandaX the Core JS Engines are similar(google v8), besides W3C standard is the only one. So in most cases if you can run it in latest chrome, it will work in latest nodejs, but remember CMD\file things in nodejs won't work in browser like `require`